# Python access C shared object

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries

Say I write a `libx.so`, it contains 3 functions,

```
void bar();
void foo();
void spam();
```

Then I use `ctypes` to access it,

```
>>>libx = ctypes.CDLL("./libx.so")
>>>dir(libx)
...
```

But how can I know how many functions `libx.so` exports and what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nm libx.so` on the shell to view the symbols exported by the library.

However, reading its docs/header file is usually a much better idea - the symbol list will not give you any information about the arguments and return values of the functions.